# WebView2 - Call/Execute Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, webview2

The `InvokeScript` method was deprecated in WebView2 so I am trying to learn the new alternative. According to the Microsft documentation, we have to call the `ExecuteScriptAsync` method in order to run a script. I was able to create an async method that executes my entire javascript function as a string and it worked. However, I find this approach not easy to debug; the `ExecuteScriptAsync` never tells you if there is a syntax error ...

How do you debug javascript code executed by the `ExecuteScriptAsync`?
Is there any other option to call javascript functions (with parameters)?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest, you save your javascript in a file, then load the file and call `AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync ` method to inject the script. The benefit is you get intellisense in VS, which will tell you when you have syntax errors. Here's the method: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.addscripttoexecuteondocumentcreatedasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.774.44#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2_AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync_System_String_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of WebBrowser.InvokeScript(String, Object\[\]) in WebView2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62835549/equivalent-of-webbrowser-invokescriptstring-object-in-webview2)

Comment: It does not really help because I don't see the need to create a function to build the script. I can just type it in. I can live with that but I need a way to debug it. The problem is that the script is loaded in memory and DevTool does not see it in run time. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: The point is that you write your javascript functions in a file (which gives intellisense and check for syntax errors) and minimize the code you write in `ExecuteScriptAsync` where there's no intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

Run your app and press <kbd>F12</kbd> or right click and choose inspect. In the dev tools go to the console. JS error will be shown there. Add console.log to your js code to see them also here.

Comment: It did not work. I voluntarily added a syntax error and the console did not show any error. 
the javascript that you passe in as a string is loaded in memory. I cannot see it in DevTools. Moreover, `ExecuteScriptAsync` method does not return an exception. It thinks that the script is correct.

Comment: Here is a link to how the console part of DevTools works. You can simply copy and paste your JavaScript in here to and you will see if it works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/console/

Comment: Do any of the answers in this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662018/console-log-not-working-at-all

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, if you use

```
await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
string result = await webView.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(myScript);
```

(`ExecuteScriptAsync` is replace with `AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync`)

then it will log syntax errors to the console.

For more detail see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69810805/3190036